# Как использовать ToolBar в Releativelayout, чтобы были Widht и Height

Tags: android

Как использовать ToolBar в Releativelayout, чтобы были Widht и Height?

Почему у RelativeLayout нет Width и height. Они мне нужны чтобы отцентровать элементы внутри, или даже переместить справа снизу. но их как видите нету. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для расположения элементов внутри ```RelativeLayout``` есть специальные свойства, для этого не нужно знать размеры самого ```RelativeLayout``` - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position . А вообще, вы что-то странное пытаетесь сделать, опишите подробней вашу задачу.

Comment: @temq, хочу создать тоолбар и добавить к нему элементы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent" </RelativeLayout>
```